# VB script to extract a cell value and store in a separate file

Tags: excel

i want to run a vb script to extract one particular cell value from each sheet and paste it into a new workbook,in addition to this, this value can also be present in separate excel files

```
Sub Macto()
' Create Excel object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
' Open the workbook
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
    ("C:\Users\x.pr\Desktop\vbscript.xlsx")
' Set to True or False, whatever you like
objExcel.Visible = True

' Select the range on Sheet1 you want to copy
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A11:C11").Copy
' Paste it on Sheet2, starting at A1
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
' Activate Sheet2 so you can see it actually pasted the data
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? [Edit] the question and show your [mcve].

Comment: Sub Macto()
' Create Excel object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
' Open the workbook
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
    ("C:\Users\narayanan.pr\Desktop\vbscript.xlsx")
' Set to True or False, whatever you like
objExcel.Visible = True

' Select the range on Sheet1 you want to copy
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C11").Copy
' Paste it on Sheet2, starting at A1
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
' Activate Sheet2 so you can see it actually pasted the data
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
End Sub

Comment: the above is what i tried

Comment: [Edit] the question and make sure it is stand-alone and contains everything someone can use to answer it -- and this includes your [mcve]. Don't hide code in a comment. Comments are not part of the Q&A. Did you take the [tour]? Because SO is not a threaded forum. No one will read code stuffed into comments. Also, once you [edit] this question and show your code, tell us what results you got. Show all your research.

Comment: sorry jdv , a lil new to this , ill get used to it :-)  am i doing it right ?

Comment: @narayanan_pr Pretty much - the edit button is below the tags in the question, and should format as code (click the `{ }` icon).  If you put a @ before someones user name they get a notification when you reply.

Comment: Did you take the [tour] and read [ask]? Tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, show your research, and show your results.